# Can I always replace DynamicResource with a Binding to a Source=StaticResource

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

What is the difference between A and B both will work.
Can I always replace *inplace* DynamicResource with a Binding to a StaticResource?

```
<Button Content="{DynamicResource content}">
    <Button.Resources>
        <sys:String x:Key="content">A</sys:String>
    </Button.Resources>
</Button>

<Button Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource content}}">
    <Button.Resources>
        <sys:String x:Key="content">B</sys:String>
    </Button.Resources>
</Button>
```

As this doesn't work (because it is defined after it is used):

```
<Button Content="{StaticResource content}">
    <Button.Resources>
        <sys:String x:Key="content">C</sys:String>
    </Button.Resources>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary difference between `StaticResource` and `DynamicResource` is that a `StaticResource` only provides a value once, when the Xaml (or Baml) is parsed and applied.  Despite what another answer says, a `StaticResource` is **not** resolved at compile time.

A `DynamicResource` provides an *expression value*, where the expression is a 'live' resource reference that can respond to changes in the future.

For a `StaticResource` to be applied, the requested resource **must** be in scope when the markup extension is asked to provide a value.  If it's not in scope, the resource lookup will fail.  This is not true for a `DynamicResource`: if the requested resource is not in scope, no value will be applied.  If the resource comes into scope later on, it will get picked up.  Similarly, if the referenced resource gets removed or replaced, the target property will be updated accordingly.

Because `DynamicResource` provides an *expression* for a value, it can only be applied to a **dependency property**.  A `StaticResource` can be applied to *any* property that is capable of receiving a markup extension.

With that in mind, let's revisit your question:

> Can I always replace [an] in-place `DynamicResource` with a `Binding` to a `StaticResource`?

You can replace a `DynamicResource` with a `StaticResource` **if and only if**:

1. The resource will be in scope when the Xaml is loaded.
2. The resource will not be replaced at runtime.

If the above conditions are known to be true, then it's better to use a `StaticResource`, because static resources are more lightweight than dynamic resources.  Using a dynamic resource necessarily requires some additional overhead because change listeners need to be hooked up.

However, it makes little sense to replace `{DynamicResource content}` with `{Binding Source={StaticResource content}}`.  If all you want to do is insert a resource reference, there is no point in wrapping it a `Binding`.  Just use `{StaticResource content}`.

There *are* times when you might want to use a `StaticResource` for a binding's `Source`, but it only makes sense if you're drilling down to a value *inside* the resource, or if you need to apply a converter.

> As this doesn't work (because it is defined after it is used):
>
> ```
> <Button Content="{StaticResource content}">
>   <Button.Resources>
>     <sys:String x:Key="content">C</sys:String>
>   </Button.Resources>
> </Button>
> ```

Right.  To use a `StaticResource` directly, you would need to move the resource to an outer scope or set `Content` *after* the `Resources` (using the `<Button.Content>` element syntax).

Now, about this guy:

> ```
> <Button Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource content}}">
>   <Button.Resources>
>     <sys:String x:Key="content">B</sys:String>
>   </Button.Resources>
> </Button>
> ```

Are you *sure* this works?  For me, it works in the designer, but if I actually *run* the application, it fails just like it does when using `StaticResource` directly.

Comment: About the last item, I was mistaken. It oddly enough only works in the designer.

Answer (score 1):

`DynamicResource` is resolved during runtime
while `StaticResource` is resolved during compile time and placed in the `BAML`.
If they work then your ResourceDictionaries are resolved correctly.
They both work that's right but they "work" in 2 different ways.
*Can I always replace DynamicResource with a Binding to a StaticResource?*
You can. Primarily one would use `DynamicResource` when loading time of the Window or UserControl takes a long time.
**EDIT**
After your edit I can tell you that the resource that you are trying to use is defined after your attempt to use it. If you move that resource to the top of the Visual Tree i.e. Window or UserControl then it will be available to you. This is because the compiler is trying to resolve the name `content` which at this point doesn't exists yet. If you would use a DynamicResource which would be resolved during runtime rather than compile time, then you would see the difference.
**EDIT 2**
As EdPlunket pointed out the `StaticResource` if changed will not be reflected on the screen, however if you change the `DynamicResource` then it will be updated.
**EDIT 3**
I should have probably made this more clear that `DynamicResource` `StaticResource` are Markup Extensions that resolve Resources used within the app. Also worth mention that `x:Static` and `x:Type` are Markup Extensions` as well.

Comment: So what's the difference between A and B? The resource is defined after the staticresource.

Comment: The difference is that if the resource is replaced at runtime, after initialization, DynamicResource will update and StaticResource will not. This doesn't affect your example case.

Comment: Thanks. But StaticResource and DynamicResource aren't types of resources. They're two different (and not very well named) markup extension subclasses used to retrieve resources. A resource is a resource.

Comment: So why is the staticresouce that is referenced via the binding (case B) resolved correctly during compile time as it is defined after it is used?

Comment: @Wouter really? I can't run my app if I create Button with that syntax.

Comment: @XAMINAX Great, visual studio designer likes it :) but I didn't really get it. Should have build it before asking.